# Может ли взаимодействовать код из функции в dll с кодом вызывающего?

Tags: c++, dll, export

Возник вопрос, может ли код функции как то взаимодействовать с кодом из вызывающей программы? Например, в своей я вызываю импортированную функцию из dll, она может как то взаимодействовать с условной переменной "int a", которая определена в моей программе? Подскажите метод если такое можно реализовать

Comment: Устраивает — передать в функцию адрес этой переменной? :)

Comment: Из программы тоже можно импортировать код, который будет вызывать dll.

Comment: extern символы из загрузочного модуля, содержащего main должны быть доступны по имени  функциям в .dll после  `hModule = GetModuleHandle( NULL );`  (я посмотрел на реализацию dlopen для винды [вот тут](https://github.com/dlfcn-win32/dlfcn-win32/blob/master/src/dlfcn.c))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, может. Вы можете передать функции указатель на переменную и уже используя указатель менять значение переменной.

```
auto SomeFunction(int*pointerToVariable);
```